# changing geometry without using newgeometry

Tags: formatting, margins, geometry

I'm using a template which I don't exactly know how it works.

In the document I to create a space for notes on the side of all the document, so I used \geometry{outer=200pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginpar= 150pt}.
This solution wasn't the best because the first few pages where I have the title and the content table shouldn't have the outer margin.

My next solution was to insert a \newgeometry{outer=200pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginpar= 150pt} after the first few pages, but some other things in the geometry were modified which they weren't when I used geometry before.
A footer next to the page count that is automatically done by the layout was moved and the lenght of the text was diminished.

I'm clueless, is there a way to modify the first 2 pages and maybe the rest without using geometry?

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.  All document classes that I'm familiar with set up the basic geometry, so making modifications via patches is possible.  But how it's done depends intimately on how the particular document class does this.  Suggesting more depends on what class (and possibly packages) you're using.

Comment: I'm using \documentclass[letterpaper,openany,nodeprecatedcode]{dndbook}

Comment: I don't know that class.  But the best way to get a knowledgeable answer is to include in your question an example that demonstrates the problem, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.